# A simple application of Noether's theorem in Peskin's and Schroeder's book

Tags: physics, proof-explanation, mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory

I am trying to understand the subsection on Noether's Theorem in the second chapter of Peskin's as Schroeder's book. I am trying to understand the simplest example they give as follows (I am going to try to be as detailed as possible in order to "debug" my thoughts easily):

Consider the Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}(\phi,\partial_\mu\phi)=\frac{1}{2} (\partial_\mu\phi)^2$ and the transformation $T$ given by $T(\phi)=\phi'$ where $\phi'(x)=\phi(x)+\alpha$ with $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$.

Notice that 
$$
    \mathcal{L}'(\phi,\partial_\mu\phi):=\mathcal{L}(\phi',\partial_\mu\phi')= \frac{1}{2} (\partial_\mu\phi')^2=\frac{1}{2} (\partial_\mu(\phi+\alpha))^2=\frac{1}{2} (\partial_\mu\phi)^2
$$

So $\mathcal{L}'=\mathcal{L}+\alpha\partial_\mu \mathcal{J}^\mu$ with $\partial_\mu \mathcal{J}^\mu=0$. Notice that any "divergenceless" $4$-vector field $\mathcal{J}$ will do.

Using Noether's Theorem directly as stated in Peskin's and Schroeder's book, we see that
$$
  \partial_\mu j^\mu=0 \,\,\,\,\text{ where }\,\,\,\, j^\mu=\partial_\mu \phi\Delta\phi-\mathcal{J}^\mu
$$
because $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi)}=\partial_\mu \phi$

Now, the conclusion of the authors is that $j^\mu=\partial_\mu\phi$, but I do not see why: it seems to me that *any* $\mathcal{J}$ will do, the job, and even if one chooses $\mathcal{J}=0$, one gets  $j^\mu=\partial_\mu\phi\Delta\phi$.

Comment: Don't you mean $j^\mu = \partial ^\mu \phi$? Note $\frac{\partial \mathcal {L}} {\partial(\partial_\mu \phi)} = \partial^\mu \phi$. I don't think I understand your difficulty: The THM guarantees a conserved current, but muliplying by a constant or adding a constant would surely give you a divergeneless quantity. Also adding a divergeneless quantity would keep it that way. I think $\mathcal{J}$ just expresses the generaility of that divergeneless current.

Comment: It seems you're misunderstanding the role of $\mathcal{J}$: it's there because $\phi(x)\mapsto \phi(x)+\alpha\,\Delta \phi(x)$ is assumed to leave the *action* invariant, but not necessarily the Lagrangian density. The Lagrangian density could potentially change by the addition of a term $\partial_\mu\mathcal{J}^\mu$ term *without* affecting the action. In the specific case $\mathcal{L}(\phi,\partial_\mu\phi) = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu\phi)^2$, however, the symmetry $\phi(x)\mapsto \phi(x)+\alpha$ keeps the Lagrangian density invariant, which means $\mathcal{J}^\mu = 0$ in this case.

Comment: @user17945 Yes, but I do not see how you conclude that $\mathcal{J}=0$: the lagrangian being invariant just means that $\partial_\mu \mathcal{J}=0$...

Comment: @Ranc So let me see if I get it:
$$
\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu \phi)} = 
\frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_\mu \phi)} ( \partial_\mu\phi )^2= \frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_\mu \phi)} ( \eta^{\alpha\beta}\partial_\alpha\phi \partial_\beta\phi )=
$$
$$
 \frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_\mu \phi)} ( \partial_0\phi \partial_0\phi - \partial_i\phi \partial_i\phi )=
\begin{cases}
\partial_\mu\phi,\,\mu=0  \\
-\partial_\mu\phi,\,\mu\ne 0
\end{cases}=\eta^{\mu\beta}\partial_\beta\phi=\partial^\mu\phi
$$
This seems overly complicated...

Comment: @Soap, yes, I agree, but you just calculated it yourself. Another way to check yourself: $\mathcal{L}$ is a scalar, and $\partial_\mu \phi$ is a covector. Derivative with respect to a co-vector is a vector. Derivative with respect to a vector is a co-vector. This is why we write $\partial_\mu = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x^\mu}$.

Comment: @Soap, just wanted to add another word on this (perhaps to clarify things for me aswell): This is practically the same as differentiating expressions such as $f(\mathbf{x}) = \| \mathbf{x}\|^2 = \langle \mathbf{x} , \mathbf{x} \rangle $ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. $Df(\mathbf{x})$ is the *row* vector $2\mathbf{x}^T$.  $Df(\mathbf{x})$ is a linear functional (member of the cotangent space) acting on vectors (members of the tangent space).

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying now. Well sure, if you have any function $\mathcal{J}^\mu = \mathcal{J}^\mu(x)$ which satisfies $\partial_\mu\mathcal{J}^\mu$, it can also be added to the conserved quantity $j^\mu$ and still give a conserved quantity, and it works no matter what your original Lagrangian density its. But this is uninteresting. This is the equivalent to adding a constant onto the conserved quantity in a Lagrangian *particle* theory and still getting a conserved quantity...

Comment: The interesting case is when under the symmetry, $\mathcal{L}(\phi,\partial_\mu\phi) \mapsto \mathcal{L}(\phi,\partial_\mu\phi) + \partial_\mu\mathcal{J}^\mu$ with $\mathcal{J}^\mu = \mathcal{J}^\mu(\phi,\partial_\mu\phi)$ (as for example happens in the calculation of the stress-energy tensor, cf (2.17)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition given in the Peskin's and Schroeder's book for a general continuous transformation on the field $\phi$ is: 
$$ T(\phi)=\phi′\:\:\:\:\:\: where \:\:\:\:\:\:\phi′(x)=\phi(x)+\alphaΔ\phi(x)$$

In this example, as you said, the transformation is 
$$ϕ′(x)=ϕ(x)+α$$ so the term $Δϕ(x)=1$.